# Reading accented filenames in VB6

Tags: vb6, internationalization

I have a VB6 application that does a directory listing of a folder and picks up the filenames. Some of these are accented, for example "Guimarães.txt" (small A with a tilde). Both the VB Dir function, and FileSystemObject functions are unable to recognise the accented character, and instead return the filename as "Guimar?es.pdf", so I am subsequently unable to open the file. I can see the file correctly in Windows Explorer

This is only happening in one live environment, running Windows Server 2003 R2. On our test systems, we can read the file correctly, though these are mainly Windows 2008 and Windows 7. I initially thought it was down to the version of FSO, but as "Dir" gives the same results, I no longer think so. Also, when I write the name of the file to a log file, it is also incorrect. So I think that at a very early stage it is unable to handle the character, and replaces it with a question mark.

What I need to establish is the cause of the issue: is it down to the version of Windows, or my regional settings (which I am unable to view, as my account is locked down), and what can I do to resolve the problem. For now, I've asked the users not to use these characters, but this is not a long-term solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suspect the problem is related to VB6 and its lack of support for Unicode.

Comment: Try setting "Language for non-Unicode programs" in Regional Settings to Portuguese and see if that fixes the issue. I believe it should. Unfortunately, I doubt old MS VB Runtime supports Unicode, just like Cody says.

Comment: The underlying cause is indeed that VB6 tries to use only one byte to encode 100.000 different characters. Some letters will lose. Changing the language just changes which letters will lose. But ã? That's U+00E3, i.e. in ISO-8859-1/CP1252, which is by far the most common.

Comment: I can't personally change the "Language for non-Unicode programs", though I could ask for it to be changed. However, it is a terminal server, supporting both US and Brazilian users, so not sure how happy they would be! It works okay in my own UK English environment. I should be able to compare codepages using chcp?

Comment: the code page is 936 (Chinese - as well as the US and Brazilian users, there are also some Chinese, though not sure why that is the default). I'll read up some more on codepages, for example, are they user or system based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the file name being read off disk uses unicode.
When you try and display this, the font in use doesn't support that glyph so it shows the "?", but writing it to disk writes the correct representation.
When this is then passed to the file functions, it's "converted" to MBCS or another charset which then breask.

You can either change your code to use the native wide Win32 API calls, or just change the "langauge for non unicode programs" to match the language used in the filename.

Comment: Thanks. As noted above, I believe it is due to Chinese being the default. However, does the "Language for Non Unicode Programs" definitely apply to VB6? I ask as its unicode capability is somewhat vague.

Comment: VB6 itself is unicode, but sadly, most of its interactions with the outside world are via interfaces that convert to/from unicode to multibyte characters (which is where the "non unicode applications" comes into play)